# Without association select all records from two differnet tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Without association I want to fetch records from two different table.

**Note**:

- In name column, to identify I want to add table name. (i.e: t1 test1)
- There is no relationship between two tables

```
TABLE A
uid  name    email
1   test1   a@a.com
2   test2   b@a.com
3   test3   c@a.com
4   test4   d@a.com

TABLE B
pid  name    email
1   test1   123@a.com
2   test2   456@a.com
3   test3   789@a.com
4   test4   900@a.com

RESULT

uid    pid      name        email

1     null    t1-test1     a@a.com
2     null    t1-test2     b@a.com
3     null    t1-test3     c@a.com
4     null    t1-test4     d@a.com
null    1     t2-test1     123@a.com
null    2     t2-test2     456@a.com
null    3     t2-test3     789@a.com
null    4     t2-test4     900@a.com
```

**My try so far:**

```
SELECT  distinct table1.id, table1.name, table.email, table2.id, table1.name, table.email
FROM table1, table2
```

Above query giving repeated records

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags, please add only the relevant tags for the technology you use. This looks you you need to *union* your data sets.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh postgres

Comment: Not the solution here, but you should switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
(
        SELECT
            row_number() OVER (),
            NULL,
            't1-' || a.name AS name,
            a.email
        FROM
            a)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL,
        row_number() OVER (),
        't2-' || b.name,
        b.email
    FROM b
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Comment: One word of warning (from experiense). Union filter duplicates. So if you happen to have exact similar rows on both tables and you want to end up as many rows in your resultset as you have in both tables together use `UNION ALL`. This is general with UNION, not neccessary related to this specific scenario, since you have prefix on a name column by table.

Comment: @mark I updated the question can you please assist me.

Comment: @ex4 you are right. We should explicitly use union all or union distinct.

Comment: Thanks @Mark code working as expected

Answer (score 1):

I think a SQL [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)  and the [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function should help you out here.

```
SELECT table1.id, CONCAT('t1-',table1.name) as name, table1.email
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.id, CONCAT('t2-',table2.name) as name, table2.email
FROM table1
ORDER BY name
```